# showing independence of random variable and arithmetic mean

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X_1 , X_2 $ be iid random variables
and  $ \bar{X} := \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i $.

I should answer the questions whether

1.) $ X_1 $ and $ X_1 - \bar{X} $ are independent

2.) $ X_1 - \bar{X} $ and $ X_2 - \bar{X} $ are independent

but I have no clue how solve this question.
Covariance are both $0$.
Can you help me?

Comment: Note $n = 2$ thus $\bar{X} = (X_1 + X_2)/2$.

Comment: What do we know about the distribution of $X_i$? For the second problem, we have $X-X_1=(X_2-X_1)/2$ and $X-X_2=(X_1-X_2)/2$. These are usually not independent. But if $X_1=X_2$, and each is $0$ with probability $1$, then they are independent.

Comment: These random variables are normal distributed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

As a simple example, suppose $X_1$ and $X_2$ independently each take the values $-1,+1$ each with probability $\frac12$.  Then the equally probable possibilities are

```
X1   X2  Xbar X1-Xbar X2-Xbar 
-1   -1   -1     0       0
-1   +1    0    -1      +1
+1   -1    0    +1      -1
+1   +1   +1     0       0
```

How would you answer your questions for this example?

Alternatively consider the general covariance of (1) $ X_1 $ and $ X_1 - \bar{X} $ and (2) $ X_1 - \bar{X} $ and $ X_2 - \bar{X} $, in terms of the variance of $X_1$ and $X_2$